# What is C2H33O28? (Empirical Formula to Molecular Formula)

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, mole

I'm doing the final question on my homework, and got an issue with this question:

> "A 76.8g sample of a liquid used as a coolant in automobiles is found to contain 3.7 g of carbon, 5.1 g of hydrogen and the rest is oxygen.  The formula weight of the compound is 60.0 g/mol.  What is its molecular formula?"

After scouring the web, youtube, and my textbook, I can't find any reason my answer doesn't make sense. My math is as follows:

---

Convert each of the given masses to moles, resulting in 0.30805mol of Carbon, 5.1mol of Hydrogen, & 4.25mol of Oxygen. Dividing by the small to convert to a ratio, the result is 1mol of Carbon, 16.5mol Hydrogen, and 14mol Oxygen. Finally, to get a whole number for the ratio of moles, multiply by 2, resulting in C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>33</sub>O<sub>28</sub>.

The issue with this, is that both the mass is way too large for what we are learning, and when converting this formula to a molecular formula by dividing the given mass of the molecular formula by the mass of the empirical formula results in a 0.12 multiplier. Multiplying each of the subscripts by 0.12 gives an odd result of C<sub>0.237</sub>H<sub>4</sub>O<sub>3</sub>.

---

I have no idea what I did wrong here besides maybe rounding, but after trying this four separate times with different rounding. If anyone can provide any insight whatsoever, I would be ecstatic, thank you so much!

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a typo somewhere in the question? Your approach seems reasonable, but the resulting formula is not a sensible molecule.

Comment: @Rocky The data is wrong. It seems the sample mass is off. Don't bother to waste your time and ask your teacher about the numbers.

Comment: Alright, I'll ask her tomorrow, thank you for the help!

Comment: Try "30.7 g of carbon".

Comment: Notice there is said liquid, not compound. In the car cooling context, it looks like water solution of ethylenglykol. From element ratio should be possible to calculate concentration. Unfortunately, M=62 g/mol.